# WPF UserControls Properties

Tags: wpf, user-controls, properties

I have a question regarding WPF UserControls and MVVM Pattern, I need to expose a Property form my ViewModel so that it is visible in the Properties box (when the UserControl is placed on the MainWindow) so that the user of my WPF Control can set the value of the new property at design time.

This is easy when I put my custom Property get/set in the UserControl.xaml.cs file but this seems to violate MVVM rules.

Normally I can find the answer to most of the problems I come across but I am stumped now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to create a dependency property.  Here's a good guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx

Be sure to read through fully and understand that the get/set won't be called for example with bindings - the internal property system will handle that. Hope that helps :)

...

Just noticed you're talking about adding a property to the ViewModel - but then talk about a .xaml.cs file.  Those are different things, the .xaml.cs is part of the View (XAML+code-behind) - it should *bind* to a ViewModel.  Are you sure you have everything correct?

Comment: I agree with Kieren.  If you are adding a custom property to your usercontrol which will be persisted into the XAML, you wouldn't want it to be on your viewmodel, but rather just add it as a property or dependency property (either one) to your codebehind.  Then you can set the value in the XAML (not 100% sure about the property editor, but I assume it reflects the properties.

Comment: Yes, i agree with what you are saying here, but surly placing the code for the property (that I want shown in the property editor) in the MyControlView.xaml.cs (Codebehind) is deviating from the MVVM rules
I’m thinking that there must be an alternative method for declaring custom properties for a UserControl that replaces the code-behind in MyControl.xaml.cs and satisfies MVVM.

Comment: MVVM doesn't impose such rules.  If your View needs a property, add it.  That said it should be a property of the view, i.e. not related to anything businessy at all, entire related to the UI